# app / script to show internet availability for a connected wifi or lan in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, internet, gui, lan

Is there any application / script for Ubuntu which shows internet availability for a connected WiFi ?

In windows if a WiFi or LAN does not have internet connectivity a yellow triangle alert is shown on WiFi symbol, but in case of Ubuntu nothing like that is displayed, is there any app for Ubuntu by which i can achieve something like that ?

I just want status of my WiFi i,e internet is available or not in that WiFi, so that i can connect to another WiFi. i don't like every time opening a browser and checking or pinging google.com .

Comment: Depending on your Ubuntu/Desktop version, there are different applications. Which one do you use (Unity, Gnome, XFCE, LXDE, ...)?

Comment: @ridgy iam using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop version 64 bit , unity.

Comment: As I am not familiar with unity (just xfce and lxde), I don't know if (and how) the gnome nm-applet works with unity. This applet is able to show the state of your network connection in the systray. Maybe [NetworkManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager) or someone using unity could help.